# Java Iterate array with a fixed length and take values with Scanner class

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, java.util.scanner

How can i get the value of a java array using Scanner class with a fixed length of 2, and which will iterate until its value is equal to a given value?
For example; for the following inputs,

```
   A G 

   N H

   D F
```

I wrote a for loop to take the values of fixed array road, in which the length is 2 using Scanner class.

```
 for(int i = 0; i<block.length; i++){
        System.out.println("enter number");
        block[i]=input2.next().charAt(0);
 }
```

I want to iterate this loop while the user input is {'C','C'}. THat means the array loop shpuld stop if the inputs are as follow;

A G

N H

D F

C C

How can i write the code to take user input values using Scanner class and to iterate the array? And the user input values should be copied without replacing them with newly entered values.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want to *populate* an array? Your question is pretty confusing.

Comment: The array length is fixed. That is array length is 2. But i want to iterate the array as i have shown in example. (The length will remain unchanged)

Comment: What is the relevance of the Scanner class? Why do you want to use it?

Comment: @dnk: It's still not clear what you mean. Usually when someone talks about iterating over an array, they're talking about *reading* from it - but it sounds like you're probably trying to *write* to it. Basically, we can't tell what you're trying to ask at the moment.

Comment: Scanner class is to take user input values.

Comment: How can i write a java code to take user input values and the input will be like the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] block = new char[2];
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 0;
        o:
        while (block[0] != 'C' && block[1] != 'C') {
            System.out.println("enter character");
            block[i % 2] = input2.next().charAt(0);
            i++;
            arrayList.add(input2.next());
            if(arrayList.size()>=2){
            if(arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-1).equals("C") && arrayList.get(arrayList.size()-2).equals("C"))
            {
                break o;
            }
            }
        }
   System.out.println(arrayList);
```

Comment: Thank you! how can i refer to each item in a specific array. For example, how to refer the first item in the first array user entered? Or the second item in the third array?

Comment: charAt(0) -it means the first character that the user entered, but in a single entry

Answer (score 2):

assuming that your block and input2 variables are already set up and your loop as shown is working, put that loop inside a controller loop

```
 do {
    for(int i = 0; i<block.length; i++){
        System.out.println("enter number");
        block[i]=input2.next().charAt(0);
    }

 } while (block[0] != 'C" && block[1] != 'C' )
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Can you please tell me how can i refer ech array? For example, the first array first item or The the third array second item likewise?

Comment: As things stand you are not keeping a copy of each array. You need somewhere to store each array you read. To show you how to do that we need to know what kind of processing you want to do with the arrays. Do you care about the order in which you read them? Do you need to sort them? Give a bit more context in your question.

Comment: Yes, i want to keep copied each input array without replacing each array as in the above code. Shall i put a for loop inside it and save each input arrays value?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this

```
char[] block = new char[2];

while (block[0] != 'C' && block[1] != 'C') {
    System.out.println("enter number");
    block[0]=input2.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("enter number");
    block[1]=input2.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following from your question

1. You have an array of fixed length into which you would like to read
   values using a Scanner
2. Once you read values into the array,you would like to compare this
   array with values from another array and do something if the input
   array matches your array.

This is a simple program that does this:

```
    String[] scannedValues=new String[2];
    String[] matchValue={"X","Y"};
    boolean isMatched=false;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(!isMatched)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<scannedValues.length;i++)
        {
            scannedValues[i]=s.nextLine();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<scannedValues.length;i++)
        {
            if(matchValue[i].equals(scannedValues[i]))
                isMatched=true;
            else
                isMatched=false;
        }
            if(isMatched)
                s.close();
    }
```

You can use some of the Scanner methods such as `nextInt()` etc for finding various types of values.You can also pass regular expressions to the Scanner such as `next("[A-Z]{1}")`
However,in case you use a regular expression be aware that a mismatch between the input provided by the user and your expression will cause an InputMismatchException.