# Iterate Java array with fixed length to take user input values without replacing former values

Tags: java, arrays, loops

How to loop a Java array with fixed length of 2 to iterate without replacing the previous values? The following code will take user input values iterating the loop. But it will replace the previous values:

```
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] block = new char[2];
while (block[0] != 'C' && block[1] != 'C') {
    System.out.println("enter number");
    block[0]=input2.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("enter number");
    block[1]=input2.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println(block);
}
```

The array should stop iterating if user enters C,C for the array.

Thank you

Comment: You have already asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604774/java-iterate-array-with-a-fixed-length-and-take-values-with-scanner-class/19604986#19604986). Kindly edit your question there itself if possible.

Comment: You should iterate it with the for loop.

Comment: @Jhanvi i want to copy the user input values without replacing them with newly entered values.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? The loop will switch between index `[0]` and `[1]` each iteration.

```
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] block = new char[2];
int i = 0;
while (block[0] != 'C' && block[1] != 'C') {
    System.out.println("enter number");
    block[i%2]=input2.next().charAt(0);
    i++;
    System.out.println(block);
}
```

Comment: The code is too long? That doesn't make any sense. What exception do you get exactly?

Comment: line is too long, please switch to wrapped mode to see whole line

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do this:

1. Use a self-size-increasing data structure like a `HashMap`.  Probably best solution
2. Create a large 2D array `char[][] block = new char[100][2];`.This will only work up to 100 inputs

With the second approach, you need to increase the array, whenever the max amount is reached, which is pretty point pointless, becuase then you'd be pretty much implementing what's under the hood of a data structure anyway.

My suggestion is to go with a `HashMap`, but I'm assuming you have not learned data structures yet.  The only thing I can suggest, if this is an assignment, is to just go with a 2D array with a set size and only allow so many inputs.